# How to add a tooltip using IValueConverter

Tags: wpf, xaml, ivalueconverter

I am looking for a solution to add a tooltip for a button using value converter.
This is because some part/text of this tooltip is calculated dynamically.

For instance i have an application with some "launchable" tasks in it in such a way that clicking any/all of these tasks launches another application.
In this task list, there is a button "Launch Tasks" with count depending upon the no. of tasks selected to launch.I need to show a tooltip for this button only.Like:
"Launch Tasks(2)", this is for two tasks selected.

Can someone please help in writing a converter for the same and then how to bind the same in XAML?

Update:

Earlier it is something like as below, but problem is tooltip shown is not upto the standards and not clearly visible, so i thought of removing the same and used converter instead.

```
<ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                            <ToolTip>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="ttlblActivityCount" Text="{Binding LaunchTaskButtonTitle, Source={StaticResource ResourceData}}" />
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="ttlblActivityCountStart"
                                               Margin="2,0,0,0"
                                               Text="("/>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="tttxtActivityCount" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedActivitiesCount}"/>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="ttlblActivityCountEnd"
                                               FontWeight="Bold"
                                               Text=")" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </ToolTip>
                        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
```

Comment: do you have to use a `IValueConverter`? if the "count" value is a property, in your `Button.Tooltip` just have `StringFormat` with the static text and property for count in the format you wish.

Comment: Please go through the update i added.

Answer (score 2):

Using a `StackPanel` to artificially combine a string is yes pretty much something you don't want to do. However you **don't have** to use an `IValueConverter` for this

If you have a property for `SelectedActivitiesCount` and you want to bind it's tooltip with some static text and the property a simple example could be:

```
<Button Content="Launch Tasks">
  <Button.ToolTip>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedActivitiesCount, StringFormat=Launch Tasks({0})}" />
  </Button.ToolTip>
</Button>
```

^^ With this output would look like: "Launch Tasks(2)" where `SelectedActivitiesCount` -> 2

If the text("Launch Tasks") is also dynamic:

```
<Button Content="Launch Tasks">
  <Button.ToolTip>
    <TextBlock>
      <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} ({1})">
          <Binding Path="LaunchTaskButtonTitle" Source="{StaticResource ResourceData}" />
          <Binding Path="SelectedActivitiesCount" />
        </MultiBinding>
      </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
  </Button.ToolTip>
</Button>
```

^^ With this output would look like: "Launch Tasks(2)" where `SelectedActivitiesCount` -> 2, `LaunchTaskButtonTitle` -> Launch Tasks

Choose whichever method is applicable for you.

Comment: Thanks Viv for the fast response.I tried both the solutions you just posted but unfortunately tooltip shown is same as earlier, i mean the block is too small and very difficult to read the text.

Comment: @Sandeep it works fine for me(I can upload a sample if you want) but I'm not really sure what you mean with "block is too small". If it's too small increase the font size or add an adorner or something to enlarge it.

Comment: Viv,unfortunately i am not able to upload the screenshot here to show.Is there any way i can do that?

Comment: you said "Adorner" sorry but am not aware of this?Or any way to enlarge the same?

Comment: @Sandeep Adorner is just a decorater. If all you want is the text to be large, just change `<TextBlock>` in the answer to `<TextBlock FontSize="36">` That will give you larger text. Is that what you're after?

Comment: Applying "FontSize" changes the default font styles that application is already using

Comment: @Sandeep I'm actually lost as to what your requirement is now. Can you maybe draw something in paint or Photoshop and upload an image showing your requirement. FontSize isnt the only thing you can change on a TextBlock. You can tweak any part of the style for the control to get your desired output

Comment: Problem has been resolved.Root cause is, TextBlock was assuming a style set in another style XAML. When i changed that to NULL it worked as expected and now assuming default style used across the project UI.